# py.test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file while executing through command prompt

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need your support in order to resolve the below issue. I highly appreciate it if could help here.
I have checked the related post, there was one similar issue but that is during installation. In my case, I have successfully installed the py.test, and I was using it was working as well. Post Jenkins installation I am facing the issue.  I have passed the command line in the shell script and tried to execute the Job through Jenkins it is failed. To cross-check, I have verified in the command prompt it throws " py.test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Can you please let me what all checks need to be done to rectify the issue?

Analysis from my end:

1. Checked in the system variables, there I can see python has been declared.

Regards,
Shiva

Comment: I have found a solution and resolved myself. The issue was, we have to pass both the python folder path and scripts folder path in the same directory using; semicolon. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you have an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work-around solution for that. If you uninstall jenkins from your PC and install&start jenkins from CMD with java -jar jenkins.war, it will resolve the problem. Now it can find and execute batch commands.